# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

This has been posted by ChrisF on the meta of all the other sites undergoing elections, so just in case you've missed it I'm adding it here.

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information.](http://se.awio.com/election.html)

The information presented is:

What the candidate wrote when nominating themselves.

- Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
- Up-vote/down-vote ratio
- Average reputation earned per post
- Average reputation earned per day.
- Participation in other Stack Exchange sites.
- It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on [MSO Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75454/moderator-nomination-possibly-useful-statistics)

Answer (score 1):

The information http://se.awio.com/election.html gives on nominees is valuable for the current (2012) election too.

Comment: This is the same link as the one in the question post. I am guessing you followed the link to the discussion and visited elections.SE and thought you would share the link to the earlier elections stat? In any case, they provide the same results.

Comment: @jokerdino Indeed, but the original post was about the former election. Also the link talks about Stack Exchange elections of 2011 but it lists nominees for 2012 now as you click on a site in it.

Comment: Hmm, now I get it. Effectively, you are bumping the thread for people to see 2012 nominees stat. +1 from me! :)

Comment: @jokerdino Exactly. Also by this answer getting one up-vote this question will no longer appear among the [unanswered](http://meta.askubuntu.com/unanswered) here at meta. I am trying to clean out some from them, hence my other answers.