# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://askubuntu.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta – just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: **Note:** I'm mentioning this because it was new information to me: apparently if a moderator is elected once, they needn't seek re-election. They are a mod. for life.

Comment: That makes Jeff's answer to this question make so much more sense to me now: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/917/how-many-moderators-should-we-have

Answer (score 5):

*(For closure, it seems like the winners should be announced in this thread.)*

### Welcome our new AskUbuntu overlords!

[image: profile for jrg at Ask Ubuntu, Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers]

[image: profile for bruno-pereira at Ask Ubuntu, Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers]

[image: profile for fossfreedom at Ask Ubuntu, Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers]

## Stats:

- 2,226 voters were eligible
- 880 visited the site during the election
- 353 visited the election page
- 180 voted

The results from OpenSTV:

```
Loading ballots from file askubuntu-com-2012-election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 10 candidates and 180 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 180 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Ask Ubuntu Moderator Election 2012 using Meek STV.
10 candidates running for 3 seats.

 R|jrg          |Roland Taylor|Bruno Pereira|fossfreedom  |Octavian Dami|William      |gajdipajti   
  |             |             |             |             |ean          |             |             
  |-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
  |Amith KK     |jokerdino    |UAdapter     |Exhausted    |Surplus      |Threshold    
  |             |             |             |             |             |             
====================================================================================================
 1|    34.000000|    23.000000|    26.000000|    71.000000|    11.000000|     2.000000|     1.000000
  |     5.000000|     7.000000|     0.000000|     0.000000|    25.999999|    45.000001
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidate fossfreedom has reached the threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
 2|    37.295773|    33.253516|    33.690137|    45.000013|    13.563379|     2.000000|     1.366197
  |     5.000000|     7.732394|     0.000000|     1.098591|     0.274660|    44.725353
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: fossfreedom, 0.633803.
====================================================================================================
 3|    45.859152|    40.352107|    41.521122|    49.436634|             |             |             
  |             |             |             |     2.830985|     6.711278|    44.292254
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Octavian Damiean, William, gajdipajti, Amith KK, jokerdino, and UAdapter
  | and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated. Candidate jrg has reached the
  | threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
 4|    45.311475|    42.968215|    43.602463|    44.447513|             |             |             
  |             |             |             |     3.670334|     1.594154|    44.082417
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: jrg, 0.965833 and fossfreedom, 0.567850.
====================================================================================================
 5|    44.152578|    43.552162|    44.005908|    44.200477|             |             |             
  |             |             |             |     4.088875|     0.425617|    43.977782
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: jrg, 0.939636 and fossfreedom, 0.563186. Candidate Bruno Pereira has reached the
  | threshold and is elected.

Winners are jrg, Bruno Pereira, and fossfreedom.
```

P.S. While the site only gives you links to OpenSTV for windows or mac to audit the results, it is also available in the Ubuntu repositories. [openstv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openstv) [Install openstv http://hostmar.co/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openstv)

Answer (score 3):

The information site mentioned in [Information on the moderator candidates](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/926/information-on-the-moderator-candidates) gives valuable information on the nominees. See  http://elections.stackexchange.com/ and choose Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up. In the information in the right column of https://askubuntu.com/election I read:

> After 7 days, the top 30 nominees, ordered by reputation, advance to
>   the primary phase. However, *if there are 10 candidates or less, we
>   skip directly to the election phase* [my emphasis].

We currently have 10 candidates and, thus, if we do not get one more candidate then the primary phase will we skipped. I do not know if this is a good or bad for the election as a whole but to me it seems that if people get more time to vote, e.g. by voting two times as in a primary followed by an election, we will have more people participating in the election and that seems to be a good thing.

Comment: Yes, good point. @htorque mentioned in the chat rooms he might run for moderator but I don't know if he was joking or not.

Comment: Indeed, he was. :)

Comment: Well there's now 11 candidates, when you include my own nomination :P

Comment: Actually I've withdrew my candidacy.  I received a few emails from a few people (names not disclosed) regarding my candidacy, and whether i'm "active enough".  Therefore, I"m withdrawing my candidacy.  ***BUT I SHALL RESUBMIT MY NOMINATION NEXT YEAR!***